# How to use JS to get HTML img height and set it as a variable?

Tags: javascript

In the following snippet, I'm trying to get the height of any image nested inside a particular class. Once that image height is gathered, I need to store it in a variable to be used elsewhere.

The two issues I'm running into are:

1. The second image is coming back as 0px
2. Storing the dynamic image height result as a variable

```js
let getImgHeight = (()=> {
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('.wistia img');
  images.forEach(image => console.log(`${image.clientHeight}px`));
})();
```

```html
<div class="wistia">
  <img src="https://media.moddb.com/images/members/5/4550/4549205/duck.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.thedesignwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Random-Pictures-of-Conceptual-and-Creative-Ideas-02.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: You're talking about one height however consider having multiple images. How should it work if there are several images?

Comment: I've updated the snippet to accommodate that, but the second image is returning 0px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get zero because you check the image height before it was loaded. You can easily check it if you wrap your function in some long timeout.

The better approach is to wait for all the loading images (ignoring ones that are already loaded) and after that get their height.
Here is an example below:

```js
let getImgHeight = (()=> {
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('.wistia img');
  Promise.all(Array.from(images)
         .filter(img => !img.complete)
         .map(img => new Promise(resolve => { 
                img.onload = img.onerror = resolve; })
         )
    ).then(() => {
        images.forEach(image => console.log(`${image.clientHeight}px`));
  });
})();
```

```html
<div class="wistia">
  <img src="https://media.moddb.com/images/members/5/4550/4549205/duck.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.thedesignwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Random-Pictures-of-Conceptual-and-Creative-Ideas-02.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**UPDATE 1**
As long as you want

> to set the height of the parent container

I'd suggest rewriting your code as follows:

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.wistia img');
for (const image of Array.from(images)) {
   if (image.complete) {
  image.parentElement.style.height = image.clientHeight + 'px';
   } else {
  image.onload = () => {
     image.parentElement.style.height = image.clientHeight + 'px';
  }
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="wistia">
  <img src="https://media.moddb.com/images/members/5/4550/4549205/duck.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: How would I store this image height as a variable (2nd part of my question)?

Comment: Which height? You have several images. Do you want to store them as array?

Comment: This would have been too much to explain in the OP, but I'm passing the resulting height as a variable to set the height of the parent container. This is part of a larger project where the image will be dismissed on click. Then a lazyloaded video will play. I want  the height of the video's container to remain the same while loading. Currently, when I click on the video, the parent container goes to 0px while loading, then re-expands to the size of the vide. I don't want that size to change: [example on codepen](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/yLPJJdd).

Comment: You have two images in your container. What height do you want to get as a result? First image height? Second image height? Sum of their heights? What?

Comment: Take a look at that Codepen in my previous comment. I want to get the height of the image and set the parent to that height, so the video container doesn't shrink while the video is loading.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand. Anycase you have two images inside your parent div. To the height of what image you want to set its height?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241669/discussion-between-millhorn-and-sergey-mell).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely that you're trying to get the height of an image that hasn't finished loading. The best way to deal with that is to use the `load` event listener. You can then store the height as a `data-attribute` which is one way of making it a dynamic variable.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('.wistia img');
  images.forEach(image => {
    image.addEventListener('load', e => {
      e.target.setAttribute('data-height', `${image.clientHeight}px`)
      console.log(`${e.target.clientHeight}px`);
      if (document.querySelectorAll('.wistia img[data-height]').length === images.length) {
         console.log("ALL IMAGES LOADED");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="wistia">
  <img src="https://media.moddb.com/images/members/5/4550/4549205/duck.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.thedesignwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Random-Pictures-of-Conceptual-and-Creative-Ideas-02.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: You're only returning one value. If I have multiple images on the page, which I do, I won't get the second one.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. if you look at the console (and then inspect the elements) you'll see that it is retreiving all image heights at load time. IF what you want to do is be able to loop through all the images in one fell swooop and get an array of image heights, you'll have to trigger that loop after all images have loaded - I added that to my answer

Comment: When I run your snippet, it's only returning the 419px image (broccoli), and not the duck.

Comment: Hmmm... that isn't the result I am seeing when I run the snippet. I am seeing both images report their heights, then 'ALL IMAGES LOADED'.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in JSFiddle and it worked as expected. Check the version of jQuery you're using.

[image: Here is a screenshot of JSFiddle]

Comment: There isn't any jQuery in OPs code.

Comment: In what order does JSFiddle parse the HTML and JS? OP may well have their script at  the top of the page, with it running before the images have rendered.

Comment: No jQuery here.

Comment: Actually, if you look at it [here...](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/BamzzwJ), parsing the JS before the HTML works. Putting it at the bottom of the document doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, what is ran first in JSFiddle @Sinjai
Also Kinglish could the fact he doesn't have jQuery be the issue? I mean personally I use jQuery in all of my projects. So to do this without jQuery I wouldn't be of much help.

Comment: @Command_String - Not really. There isn't anything that jQuery can do that you can't do in VanillaJS.

Comment: jQuery is just a lib that makes JS easier. It is not a different language, just different syntax. In reality, jQuery is becoming less useful because DOM manipulation is much easier with JS updates over the last 5 years.